# Identify a succulent with gray-green whorled leaves with a mosaic-like pattern

Tags: identification, succulents

[image: don't mind the baby succs everywhere, please]

I grabbed it on a whim due to the color and the crystalline patterns on the leaves. It's only my third time dealing with these small dudes so I'd like to put it outside or keep it indoors as per requirements asap.

Thank you in advance, you guys are the best!

Comment: A few of the "leaves" have been broken off. If you just put the broken leaves on a piece of paper (not planted in soil!) in bright light, they will probably start to grow roots from the base of the "leaf" within a short time. Don't attempt to water them while they are on the paper. There is enough water stored within the "leaf" to start them growing. Extra water is likely to make them rot. When the roots are about a quarter of an inch long, you can then plant the "leaf" in free draining compost and add to your collection.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can put it outdoors depends on temperatures wherever you are, you've not said. It is Pachyphytum compactum; it will not tolerate frost, but in some regions, can be stood outside during summer, and in arid, hot regions can be used for xeriscaping out doors. Temperature range required is average room temperature, but it may produce flowers if kept at a lower temperature (41-50 deg F) during the winter months. Otherwise,indoors, it needs as much bright light as it's possible to get, preferably with some sunlight. Care should be taken with watering, as with most succulent plants, to prevent root or stem rot, so the soil in its pot should be free draining (cactus mix is ideal) and its pot should have drainage holes - any outer tray or pot should be emptied out within 30 minutes of watering so it is not left sitting in water. Some further info and image here  https://houseplantz.net/pachyphytum-compactum/

In the photo, it looks as if the pot it's in might be overfilled with soil, meaning the soil appears to be right up to the top of the pot - this is not a good idea because water will simply run straight off, so you really need to correct that if that is the case, ensuring the soil level is a quarter to half an inch below the rim of the pot. It also seems to be far too big a pot for such a small plant, so a smaller pot would be best, unless you're intending to add other small succulents.

Comment: Bamboo- Can and will reduce the soil, thanks for the heads up! The place I got it from had overwatered it and I was hoping the extra soil would suck the excess moisture away from the roots before swapping soil+adding the other succulents to the pot. Eta- thank you for the ID.

Comment: As a rule, when you repot any plant, the new container should never be more than 1, (maybe 2 for other non succulent plants) sizes bigger than the pot its currently in... enough to give about half inch extra space all round. As you're adding other plants to a larger pot, best to do them all at once... If it had been overwatered, it would have been best to just leave it in its pot and withhold water till it dried out somewhat...